# Elasticsearch regex for full documents does not work

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch to store sentences. I want to find sentences matching a regular expression. I tried query_string for this, though it does not return the required sentence.

Query:

```
{
  "_source": "doc.sent", 
  "query": {
    "query_string" : {
      "query" : "/food.*table/",
      "default_field" : "doc.sent"
     }
  }
}
```

Example sentence:

```
My food is left at the table right now.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elasticsearch Regex Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411079/elasticsearch-regex-query)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need regex for this, but if you want to match multiple words or [multiple patterns, you can use `&` symbol](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#_optional_operators)

> Intersection
>   The ampersand "&" joins two patterns in a way that both of them have
>   to match. For string "aaabbb":
>
> aaa.+&.+bbb     # match aaa&bbb         # no match Using this feature
>   usually means that you should rewrite your regular expression.
>
> Enabled with the INTERSECTION or ALL flags.

For your purpose, the query would look like:

```
{
  "_source": "doc.sent", 
  "query": {
    "query_string" : {
      "query" : "food&table",
      "default_field" : "doc.sent"
     }
  }
}
```

Or you could also use [`AND`or `OR` operators](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-top-level-params)

```
   {
      "_source": "doc.sent", 
      "query": {
        "query_string" : {
          "query" : "food AND table",
          "default_field" : "doc.sent"
         }
      }
    }
```